# How to determine the projection (Stereographic, equidistant etc.) of my fisheye lens?

Tags: distortion, fisheye, projection

I have a [Fujinon FE185C057HA](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/optical_devices/pdf/cctv/fa/fisheye/fe185c057ha-1.pdf) `fisheye` lens and I want to know its projection.

Is there a software tool I can use to do this? I have the lens with me so I can take some pictures with it. I just need a quick way to tell if the projection is `equdistant`/`stereographic`/`equisolid`/`brown`/`baker`.

I also need to know the distortion parameters if the projection is `Brown` or `Baker`.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I realize the question is quite old, but it still seems to get some views.

The quickest thing that I would try first is to take a photo of a planar grid / checkerboard pattern / brick wall straight on (center of image should be perpendicular to grid surface).
Then I would use [Hugin](https://hugin.sourceforge.io/) to see if I can undistort (de-fish) the image to obtain the original grid pattern with reasonably straight lines.

Looking at the lens type, you may use it for an engineering application. One good option to calibrate such a lens is using OpenCV. I found a [tutorial how to calibrate fisheye lenses with OpenCV](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0).